# Need help creating regular expression for a specific rule

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following regular expression that does almost everything I need:

```
^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]{2,62}$
```

What I need is support for the following rule:

> Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted.

For reference, here are all the rules this regular expression must support:

> 1. Must start with a letter or number, and can contain only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character.
> 2. Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted.
> 3. All letters must be lowercase.
> 4. Must be from 3 to 63 characters long.

Comment: Do you have to get all this in one regular expression? Additionally, which regular expression dialect are we using?

Comment: This is for .NET and I would like to have it in one regular expression if possible.

Comment: I don't know .NET regexp syntax, but I think my negative-match probably follows it (once you remove the explanatory comments & spaces, at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the desired result

```
^(?-i)(?:[a-z0-9]|(?<=[0-9a-z])-(?=[0-9a-z])){3,63}$
```

`^`                                match start of string

`(?-i)`                            case insensitive

`(?:`                              begin non capturing group

`[a-z0-9]`                         match a-z or 0-9

`|`                                or

`(?<=[0-9a-z])-(?=[0-9a-z])`       match `-` aslong as its preceded and superceed by a-z or 0-9
                                   This uses look behind and look ahead

`)`                                close non capturing group

`{3,63}`                           repeat group 3 to 63 times

`$`                                match end of string

Answer (score 3):

This should meet your first three requirements:

```
^[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

The last requirement can be met by either an additional regular expression or by a look-ahead assertion, if supported:

```
^(?=.{3,63}$)[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

Comment: I ended up using `^[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$` and it will meet my needs. I can check the length requirements separately. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be what you're looking for, except for the length:

```
^([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9]-[a-z0-9])+$
```

You can't put the length on that, because the sequence `a-a` (which is allowed) would count as one repetition despite having a length of 3.

If you can negate the match, then you could do something like this (spaces and linebreaks added for readability, think perl's `/x` flag)

```
# reject if...
[^a-z0-9]      # any character other than a-z0-9
| (^.{64})     # has a 64th character
| (^.{0,2}$)   # is 0–2 characters
| (--)         # consecutive dashes 
| (^-)         # starts with dash
| (-$)         # ends with dash
```

No guarantees on the efficiency of that match.